# SQL Server : check if there is a foreign key validation without checking every single table by hand

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm working at a project of my customer where I found out there a huge problems on the running systems with his software.

A lot of people are "working" on those running databases and now the systems are extremely corrupt.

It is a big load of money to ride a script that checks every single foreign key and check if on the other table the primary key still exists.

(They didn't know what `NOCHECK CONSTRAINT` all really does!)

I was wondering if there is a way to proof this by SQL itself without searching for every single relationship?

Thanks for helping :)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "by SQL itself". Do you want to generate and execute a `CHECK CONSTRANT` script for untrusted constraints?

Comment: If you want to look for constraint violations you can run [DBCC CHECKCONSTRAINTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkconstraints-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). If you don't specify a table, all tables are checked. After fixing the violations, the constraints should be enabled again to prevent corruption in the future

Comment: _After fixing the violations..._ hahahaha

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the ask correctly you should be able to use this script to identify all FKs in a database, if the referenced names are NULL then the column(s) being referenced in the FK no longer exist. You could also leverage this for some dynamic SQL to check for any orphaned values.

```
SELECT
    KeyName = FKY.[name]
    ,ParentSchema = PSCH.[name]
    ,ParentTable = PTAB.[name]
    ,ParentColumn = PCOL.[name]
    ,ReferencedSchema = RSCH.[name]
    ,ReferencedTable = RTAB.[name]
    ,ReferencedColumn = RCOL.[name]
    ,FKY.is_disabled
FROM sys.foreign_key_columns AS FKC
    JOIN sys.foreign_keys AS FKY
        ON FKC.constraint_object_id = FKY.[object_id]
    LEFT JOIN sys.columns AS PCOL
        ON FKC.parent_object_id = PCOL.[object_id]
            AND FKC.parent_column_id = PCOL.column_id
    LEFT JOIN sys.tables AS PTAB
        ON PCOL.[object_id] = PTAB.[object_id]
    LEFT JOIN sys.schemas AS PSCH
        ON PTAB.[schema_id] = PSCH.[schema_id]
    LEFT JOIN sys.columns AS RCOL
        ON FKC.referenced_object_id = RCOL.[object_id]
            AND FKC.referenced_column_id = RCOL.column_id
    LEFT JOIN sys.tables AS RTAB
        ON RCOL.[object_id] = RTAB.[object_id]
    LEFT JOIN sys.schemas AS RSCH
        ON RTAB.[schema_id] = RSCH.[schema_id]
WHERE FKY.[name] = 'FK_Keychain_SettingBlockUtilityTile_UtilityTileID'
;
```